# How to speed up my Function App (python script)

Tags: python, pandas, azure, sqlalchemy, azure-functions

I have a blob storage trigger inside of a function app where I'm taking parquet files from a storage container, transforming the data into a dataframe and inserting the data into an Azure SQL DB.

I've eliminated any parallelism by restricting the function to one machine and setting `"batchSize": 1` in my host.json file.

I chose to do so because when I allowed the script to run in parallel, sometimes the instances would clash and try to access the same table at the same time, causing problems.

This works fine, but it's obviously fairly slow. Especially with the amount of files It's initially running on. I've also decided to not even run bigger files (files more than about 2mb) because I'd rather side load them than to keep the function held up.

I'm just looking for suggestions/direction on how I could make this process go faster? Also, is it normal for a parquet file size of 2mb or greater to take a long time for what I'm doing? I feel like 2mb is not a huge file size, but I don't have any reference to go off of.

Some additional information: My main dependencies for my script are pandas(dataframe) and SQL Alchemy (specifically to_sql() to insert data from dataframe into the DB)

Comment: SQL Server is perfectly capable of handling multiple simultaneous insertions to a single table.  Do your keys class in some way?  Are you using transactions?

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry, sometimes the files may have an extra column that does not exist and I have to account for that and replace the table with the new column. Which in turn, when running in parallel, if another instance looks up the same table and sees it doesn't exist (currently in the process of being replaced) then it will also try and create the table. Things like this were causing problems.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm not using transactions per say, SQL Alchemy is doing the heavy lifting for the most part. I'm not 100% sure if they're using transactions or not. I want to say that they do.

Comment: `pandas.to_sql` and `SQLAlchemy` are convenient and powerful helpers, but they are not designed for optimization or maximum performance.  They hide WAY too much of the detail.  If performance becomes your primary consideration, you may have to fall back to constructing the SQL yourself.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yeah, that's true. It's not a primary concern here, necessarily, just a preference. Once I go to actually run this thing, and once it catches up to all of the initial files that are in the container, it should be a cake walk. There aren't many newly added files.

Comment: @BlakeB9 It might help to include an actual code sample.  Are you recreating the entire database and table every run ?